# Number Patterns Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a number pattern:
$2,2,4,6,10,x, 42, \cdots$
Evaluate the value of $x$.

I first thought this pattern is a Fibonacci type. The key answer is $x = 16$. But the $7$th term, that is $42$, doesn't obey the pattern rule of Fibonacci. It should be $26$. 
\
It can be observed also that $16 + (10 + 16) = 42$.

This problem comes from SEAMO 2017 Middle Primary.

Comment: $x=16$ if $2\times$ (Fibonacci numbers with digits in nonincreasing order).  $x=26$ if $2\times$ (squarefree Fibonacci numbers). $x=22$ if $a_n=$ (the sum of the $2^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}$ preceding numbers) for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C2%2C4%2C6%2C10%2C16%2C_%2C42

Answer (score 1):

For the sequence $2,2,4,6,10,16,x,42,....$ I am providing answer.

{$a_i$} = $2,2,4,6,10,16,x,42,.....$

$a_i=a_{i-1}+a_{i-2}$. From this you'll get $x=26$